# Deploying django(python) project with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am new to django and mod_wsgi, when I was trying to deploy a django project(in python) demo on Apache using mod_wsgi, I encountered some problem as following:

When the demo runs on django's built-in webserver with command 'python manage.py runserver',  everything looks normal like [Running on built-in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqp0J.png)

while when running on Apache/mod_wsgi with command 'mod_wsgi-express start-server wsgi.py' , it looks like this:
[Running on Apache/mod-wsgi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAYYx.png)

I have no idea which part of my code or configuration goes wrong, could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `runserver` serves css files for you. But in production you need to set up Apache to serve your static folder. Add alias to your apache config, e.g.

```
Alias /static /path/to/static_folder
```

Read more on [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Comment: For Apache/mod_wsgi, a more appropriate link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: @loktherhal  if the answer was helpful please accept it (click check)

Comment: @VladT. Sure, sorry I am new here.